# Swapping the elements of a ArrayList-java

Tags: java

I found this code for swapping but I need to eliminate recursion? Is it possible to use an ArrayList instead of an Array?

```
public class A {

    static ArrayList<int[]> permutations(int[] a) {
        ArrayList<int[]> ret = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        permutation(a, 0, ret);
        return ret;
    }

    public static void permutation(int[] a, int pos, ArrayList<int[]> list) {
        if (a.length - pos == 1)
            list.add(a.clone());

        else
            for (int i = pos; i < a.length; i++) {
                swap(a, pos, i);
                permutation(a, pos + 1, list);
                swap(a, pos, i);
            }
    }

    public static void swap(int[] arr, int pos1, int pos2) {
        int h = arr[pos1];
        arr[pos1] = arr[pos2];
        arr[pos2] = h;
    }
```

Comment: Can you be specific about your problem? Swapping what? And in swapping I don't see any recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is simply can you swap two elements using an `ArrayList` then the answer is yes:

```
Collections.swap(arr, pos1, pos2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's quick-and-dirty non-recursive solution to find all the permutations of integer array:

```
public static List<int[]> permutation(int[] a) {
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int l = a.length;
    int permNumber = 0;
    while(true) {
        BitSet usedIndices = new BitSet();
        int[] newPermutation = new int[l];
        int rest = permNumber;
        for(int i=0; i<l; i++) {
            int curIdx = rest % (l-i);
            rest /= (l-i);
            int freeIdx = -1;
            while(curIdx >= 0) {
                do {
                    freeIdx++;
                } while(usedIndices.get(freeIdx));
                curIdx--;
            }
            usedIndices.set(freeIdx);
            newPermutation[i] = a[freeIdx];
        }
        if(rest > 0)
            break;
        list.add(newPermutation);
        permNumber++;
    }
    return list;
}
```

This code just generates a permutation based on its ordinal number. Note that number of permutations quickly grows up (as factorial of array length), so you can get `OutOfMemoryError` even on not very big arrays.